# Strip link from website using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have tried hard to get the link (i.e. `/d/Hinchinbrook+25691+Masjid-Bilal`) from "result" below while using beautifulsoup in Python. Please help?

result:

```
<div class="subtitleLink"><a href="/d/Hinchinbrook+25691+Masjid-Bilal"><b>Masjid Bilal</b></a></div>
```

code:

```
url1 = "http://www.salatomatic.com/c/Sydney+168"
content1 = urllib2.urlopen(url1).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content1)
results = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "subtitleLink"})
for result in results :
print result
br = result.find('a')
pos = br.get_text()
print pos
```

Comment: Do you just want *that* specific link, or all links?

Comment: all the links. I tried a = result.find('a') pos = br.get_text() but this gets me <a>......</a> I only want the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url1 = "http://www.salatomatic.com/c/Sydney+168"
content1 = urllib2.urlopen(url1).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content1)
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
   print link.get('href')
```

This should work if you want all the links. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: if possible, extra question, relevant to this: how can i detect if the link doesn't have "http" and if it doesn't, add it to it

Comment: You should ask a separate question for that one. (Sorry, that's how the rules are). But yeah, I (or someone else) will definitely be able to help with that.

Answer (score 2):

The [`get_text`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method returns only the string components of a tag. To get the link here, reference it as an [attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes). For this specific instance, you can change `br.get_text()` to `br['href']` to get your desired result.

```
...
>>> br = result.find('a')
>>> pos = br['href']
>>> print pos
/d/Hinchinbrook+25691+Masjid-Bilal
```